# Model booted events are not firing in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

In Laravel 7, the documentation shows we can do this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($user) {
            // Do something...
        });
    }
}
```

This has always worked just fine in earlier versions of Laravel. However, after a new install of v7, I can't get any model events to fire.

I traced that the model is indeed booting as expected. However, no registered model events actually fire.

If I put them into observers, they do work for some reason. However, observers only work on past tense events such as created, saved, deleted...not creating, saving, deleting, etc.

Am I missing a configuration somewhere that is new in L7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careless mistake on my part.

I put `Relation::morphMap()` definition in `AppServiceProvider::register()` instead of `AppServiceProvider::boot()`.

Moving this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class User extend Model {
     public static function boot()
     {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function($model)
        {
            $user = Auth::user();           
            $model->created_by = $user->id;
            $model->updated_by = $user->id;
        });
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you try by this answer?

Comment: I used the code exactly. This has always worked in previous versions of Laravel, but no longer works for me.

Comment: what's the purpose by using this method at your model?

Comment: When the model is in the process of being created, saved, etc then I need to execute specific event based code.